# How to delete (tmutil delete) all old backups from TimeMachine - keep only current full backup

Tags: terminal, backup, time-machine, macos, command-line

How to delete (with CLI `tmutil delete`) all old backups from TimeMachine. I wish to keep only current backup.

I wish to put that into `crontab`.

Found [How to Delete Old Backups from Time Machine on Mac](http://osxdaily.com/2015/07/27/delete-old-backups-time-machine-mac/)

```
sudo tmutil delete /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/MacBook\ Pro/2015-07-13-150021/
```

I don't like to specify Timestamps. I wish to have only one current full backup. This means remove deleted files and versions from backup disk.

Comment: If you want to do this often I think you are using the wrong tool try Carbon Copy Cloner or Superduper which are designed to just have one copy a

Comment: But both cost less(and not a massive amount)  than the problems of a bad backup or the time you have spent doing this - but for free look at rsync

Comment: Yeah, I Agree: messing with TM usually makes it go wrong. If you only want one copy then use another tool. Also: one copy isn't really a backup. How do you recover a deleted file if your backup is only one copy of what you currently have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of macOS Big Sur 11.2.3+ - and according to the updated `man tmutil` - you need to provide the mount point disk and the timestamp of each backup using `-d` and `-t` flags, respectively. So the following tweak is needed for the accepted answer:

```bsh
# assuming you have the backup disk connected & root privileges:
# get the latest backup to exclude from deletion
latest=$(sudo tmutil latestbackup)
# the 4th line after the last space from `tmutil destinationinfo` output
# contains the mount disk name
mountpoint=$(tmutil destinationinfo | sed '4q;d' | sed 's/.* //')
echo "latest is $latest"
# delete all the backups excluding the latest
backups=$(sudo tmutil listbackups)
echo $backups | while read timestamp; do
    if [[ "$timestamp" != "$(basename $latest)" ]]; then
        echo sudo tmutil delete -d $mountpoint -t $timestamp
    fi
done

# if you want to keep the last, say, 3 backups, pipe "sed '$d'" 3-1=2 times:
backups=$(sudo tmutil listbackups | sed '$d' | sed '$d')
```

It should look like `sudo tmutil delete -d /Volumes/TimeMachineBackups -t 2021-04-10-004103`.

Comment: MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3 here. For this command:
`sudo tmutil delete -d 2020-12-16 -t 151046.backup` I am getting this error: `151046.backup: Invalid argument (error 22)`

Comment: @bartektartanus what do you get with `tmutil listbackups`?. For me it's YYYY-MM-DD-hhmmss. In which case you might wanna remove the `.backup` suffix. I added an edit.

Comment: That won't work. `man tmutil` says: delete [-d backup_mount_point -t timestamp] [-p path]. The path is only for hfs, but you do need the mount point as well as timestamp. There is no -d argument.

Comment: @Gilby thanks for pointing this out. I just fixed it.

Comment: No. When I tried it is had to be `sudo tmutil delete -d /Volumes/.timemachine/<UUID>/<date-time>.backup -t <date-time>`. See my answer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407967/how-to-use-tmutil-delete-on-big-sur-apfs

Answer (score 9):

```
#!/bin/bash
latest=$(sudo tmutil latestbackup)
sudo tmutil listbackups | while read backup; do
    if [[ "$backup" != "$latest" ]]; then
        echo sudo tmutil delete "$backup"
    fi
done
```

Remove the `echo` once you are sure that the output is correct.

Comment: Depending on the size of those backups, the grace period granted by `sudo` may time out while `tmutil delete` runs. You probably want to just remove sudo from the script and instead run this script with sudo. Also, `tmutil listbackups` doesn't actually list the "latest" backups, at least not on my system, so your script effectively deletes ALL backups.

Comment: @DanielSmedegaardBuus Valid point about sudo, I don't understand the second remark though. The goal is to delete all but the latest backup (which gets returned by `sudo tmutil latestbackup`).

Comment: My bad, I missed that part in the script XD I did it manually myself.

Comment: currently using macOS Ventura 13.1, and `sudo tmutil delete {backup}` returns error,  `Specify either a path or a mountpoint and timestamp` and `Usage: tmutil delete [-d backup_mount_point -t timestamp] [-p path]` but adding the option `-p` before the path works (for some reason I couldn't use the `-d mount` with `-t timestamp` options without getting an error, `No such file or directory`, regardless of combinations attempted)

Comment: I was too lazy to make a script but but this approach works on macOS Ventura: 1) List all your backups with `tmutil listbackups -d /Volumes/BACKUPDRIVE`, and then 2) Delete a specific backup with `sudo tmutil delete -d /Volumes/BACKUPDRIVE -t 2022-04-05-151520`.

Answer (score 2):

macOS Sonoma Version 14.0

I have some problems with above bash code. This is my modified code that applies to me.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Assuming you have the backup disk connected & root privileges:

# Get the latest backup to exclude from deletion
latest=$(sudo tmutil latestbackup)
echo "Latest backup is $latest"

# The 4th line after the last space from `tmutil destinationinfo` output
# contains the mount disk name
mountpoint=$(tmutil destinationinfo | awk '{print $NF}' | sed -n '4p')
echo "The mountponint is $mountpoint"

# Delete all backups excluding the latest
backups=$(sudo tmutil listbackups)
# if you want to keep the last, say, 3 backups, pipe "sed '$d'" 3-1=2 times:
# backups=$(sudo tmutil listbackups | sed '$d' | sed '$d')

echo "$backups" | while read -r backup_path; do
   timestamp=$(basename "$(dirname "$backup_path")" | sed 's/\.backup$//')
   if [ "$timestamp" != "$(basename "$(dirname "$latest")" | sed 's/\.backup$//')" ]; then
      echo "Deleting backup timestamp: $timestamp"
      # if the output is correct, remove the echo
      echo sudo tmutil delete -d "$mountpoint" -t "$timestamp"
   fi
done
```

If the output is correct, remove the `echo` in `echo sudo tmutil delete -d "$mountpoint" -t "$timestamp"`