# 'tmutil listbackups' doesn't work with tmux in Mojave

Tags: terminal, time-machine, command-line, mojave, privacy

I've tried to list past TM backups while running in a `tmux` session, but the solution described in this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/281617/9058) doesn't seem to work on macOS Mojave any longer:

```
root@nomi ~> tmutil listbackups
The operation could not be completed because tmutil could not access
private application data on the backup disk. Use the Privacy tab
in the Security and Privacy preference pane to add Terminal to the
list of applications which can access Application Data.
```

I tried to grant `Terminal` access to my data:

[image]

but it doesn't work. So how do I list/delete my old backups in Mojave if I run the shell in `tmux`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run the command inside *Terminal* without any *ancestor* other than the program itself: that is no `screen` or `tmux` or any other terminal helper.

Otherwise the calling program will be the *helper* and not *Terminal* itself, and you will need to add that *helper* to the *Privacy* settings of MacOS.

---

*EDIT: add pstree info*

This happens, at least for `tmux`, because it spawns another process wich is **not** a child of iTerm/Terminal. With `pstree` I see the following:

```
-+= 00001 root /sbin/launchd
...
 | |-+= 12748 maxxer /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp maxxer
 | | \-+= 12749 root login -fp maxxer
 | |   \-+= 12750 maxxer -zsh
 | |     \--= 14144 maxxer tmux
...
 |-+= 14146 maxxer tmux
 | \-+= 14147 maxxer -zsh
 |   \--= 14170 root top
 |--= 14212 maxxer /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdworker_shared -s mdworker -c MDSImporterWorker -m com.apple.mdworker.shared
```

PID `14144` is tmux launched in iTerm2, while `14146` is the actual `tmux` program running `top` in the first shell

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error when trying to execute…

/usr/bin/tmutil  latestbackup

via Apple Remote Desktop (ARD) on my iMac to iMac Mojave Clients.

And found that adding…
ARDAgent.app
(from /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/)

to Full Disk Access (under Security and Privacy > Privacy) on the Client Target iMac  – got it to work.

In a similar fashion the presence of SSHD in …. 
Security and Privacy > Privacy Tab > Full Disk Access
will allow the command to be run via SSH from my iMac to a Client iMac.
(SSHD will be there if you’ve enabled SSH in Sharing)

Interestingly on the client iMac itself, executing … 
/usr/bin/tmutil  latestbackup
won’t work unless Terminal is added to Privacy.  But the same command executed from my iMac to target iMac via SSH or ARD 
will work, even if Terminal isn’t added to Privacy of the Client iMac. (So long as ARDAgent and SSHD are added to Privacy on the Client)

So it looks like you can run tmutil ‘under the auspices’ of ARDAgent or SSHD without having to add Terminal to Privacy

I’m sure all that can be explained in Terms of Caller and Helper etc (and I’m grateful to the above answer in solving my issue).

Incidentally – if you follow this thread:
https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=46620

A similar case where adding osascript to Privacy sorted out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `tmux` to the *Full Disk Access* list in System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Privacy. You may use the + button to open the file select dialog, then enter shift + command + G to open the *Go to folder* input. Enter the path tmux is installed to like */usr/local/bin*, click *Go* and choose `tmux` from the file list. It may be just a symlink which is fine.

Close all open tmux sessions / processes. New tmux sessions now should have full disk access.